# How to fix jinja2 exceptions Template SyntaxError:

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to use if else condition to check sent list from flask file is empty or not in html page.If list is empty print statement otherwise print it in table format.But its giving jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Unexpected end of template. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endif'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'if'error how do i fix it.

```
</div>
 {% if not reflist1234 %}
   <h1> Sorry no reference list </h1>
 {% else %}
 <table>
   <tr>
     <th><h2> Refernce List<h2></th>
   </tr>
      {% for i in reflist1234 %}
      <tr>
        <th>{{ i }}</th>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
 </table>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: That looks like a valid template. Are you sure that's where the error is coming from?

Comment: `{% if reflist1234|length < 1 %}` ?

Comment: As @rdas said, are you sure that the error is in that block? That looks like valid syntax.